# sound recording by using actionscript

Tags: flash

I want to record the sound by using  flash in server.

Comment: "Record the sound?" We really need some more info here.

Comment: Could you state that as a (specific) question, please?

Answer (score 1):

- [Audio Recording, Playback with Red5](http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/) contains a demo, the source code, and a compiled SWF

or

- [FLV Audio Recorder Flash Audio Recorder](http://flvar.com/) (commercial software)